# Analog of the Lie Product formula for commutators

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $X, Y$ be elements of a Lie algebra. Consider the group $G$ generated by (limits of) arbitrary products of the elements

$$ G = \langle{e^{tX},e^{sY}\rangle}$$
for all $t,s$. The Lie product formula tells us that $e^{u(X+Y)} \in G$. What about the commutator? E.g., for all $u$, what conditions are necessary so that
$$ e^{u [X,Y]} \in G$$
Clearly we can achieve this for ``infinitesimal'' $u$ by considering something like $e^{t X} e^{t Y} e^{-t X} e^{-t Y}$ for infinitesimal $t$. But what about for finite $u$? Is there a formula like
$$ e^{u [X,Y]} = \mathcal{P} e^{\int X t' + Y s' d\tau  }$$
for some $t(\tau), s(\tau)$? If so, is there an explicit formula for $t$ and $s$ in terms of $u$? I know of such a formula for SU(2), but I do not know how general group.

Comment: Do you want to assume anything about the ambient Lie group in which exponentials are valued?  E.g., is it compact, simply connected, …?

Comment: @LSpice for concreteness, let's say the ambient Lie group is SU(N), although I am willing to consider any examples.

Comment: Of course, upon replacing $X$ by $u X$ (which doesn't change anything else about the problem), it suffices to show that $e^{[X, Y]}$ lies in $G$.  It might be interesting work with the root-space decomposition with respect to a torus to which $X$ is tangent (which, by conjugation, we may assume to consist of diagonal matrices if it is convenient), but I can't immediately do anything with that idea.

Comment: Yamabe's theorem: every path connected subgroup of a Lie group is an immersed Lie subgroup. This implies that the commutator is in the Lie algebra of that subgroup, but doesn't give the formula.

Answer (score 7):

The formula
$$
e^{u[X,Y]}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(e^{\sqrt{u/n}\,X}e^{\sqrt{u/n}\,Y}e^{-\sqrt{u/n}\,X}e^{-\sqrt{u/n}\,Y}\right)^n
\tag{$*$}
$$
(Godement [2017](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3616786), p. [70](//books.google.com/books?id=bAbVDgAAQBAJ&ots=zmwCmAqOSU&pg=PA70&dq=%22Theorem+3%22)) shows that $e^{u[X,Y]}\in G$ always, and seems sufficiently “like” “[Lie’s](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_product_formula)” to be what you want.

**Note added:** The origin of this formula was [left unresolved](//mathoverflow.net/questions/134142/where-did-sophus-lie-write-the-group-commutator-for-two-one-parameter-groups) before. Howe ([1983](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=86m:00001a)) and Godement (originally [1982](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=85i:22001a)) point to von Neumann ([1929](//zbmath.org/?q=an:55.0245.05), §II.3) who proves $e^{u[X,Y]}\in G$, but apparently not $(*)$. Formula $(*)$ is explicit in e.g. Chorin et al. ([1978](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=58:8230), p. [207](//math.berkeley.edu/~chorin/)), Goldstein ([1970](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=41:9049)), Nelson ([1969](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=43:8091), p. 111), Goto ([1969](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=38:2244), p. 159), Hausner-Schwartz ([1968](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=38:3377), p. 78), Cohn ([1957](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=21:2702), p. 112), and somewhat implicit in Gluškov ([1957](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=101893), p. [137](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/umn/v12/i2/p137)), Yamabe ([1950](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=36766), p. [14](//projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200685927)), Yosida ([1936](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0018.39302), Remark p. [470](//doi.org/10.4099/jjm1924.13.0_459)). Almost none of whom cite each other!

Comment: Indeed, it's almost *using* the informal idea "we can compute $e^{u[X, Y]}$ for infinitesimal $u$" to compute $e^{u[X, Y]}$ for standard $u$.  (Maybe some NSA can make this precise, but, at least as a conceptual explanation, it makes sense to me.)